# installing perl module Class-Load-XS

Tags: perl

I tried to install module `Class-Load-XS-0.04` manually. I saw the following error:

```
$ perl Build.PL
Warning: ExtUtils::CBuilder not installed or no compiler detected
Proceeding with configuration, but compilation may fail during Build
```

However, the execution of `perl -e 'use ExtUtils::CBuilder'` was perfectly fine. I even tried to re-install `ExtUtils::CBuilder`, but it still does not work.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I tried on my Win 7 machine, and it shows some warnings like this when I do perl Build.pl:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Checking prerequisites...
  requires:
    !  Class::Load is not installed
  build_requires:
    !  Class::Load is not installed
    !  Module::Implementation is not installed
    !  Test::Fatal is not installed
    !  Test::Requires is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation
```

Then I installed the above mentioned modules, and things went fine then.

You may try install these modules first. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you don't have a compiler. Try this:

```
perl -e 'use ExtUtils::CBuilder; $cb = ExtUtils::CBuilder->new; print $cb->have_compiler ? "have\n" : "dont have\n";'
```

Can I guess that you are on Windows using ActiveState Perl? If so perhaps try [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.org) which comes with a compiler.

Comment: right, I got `$ perl -e 'use ExtUtils::CBuilder; $cb = ExtUtils::CBuilder->new; print $cb->have_compiler ? "have\n" : "dont have\n";'
dont have`. What compiler here are we talking about?

Comment: I am actually on cygwin. If you are saying c/c++ compilers, I of course have. If so, should I specify it in Config.pm? How to actually do that? Many thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, you're beyond my knowledge of that situation. Yes it seems that Cygwin ought to report that it has a c compiler. I don't think you can change Config.pm but perhaps there are some problems with your environment (PATH etc). Sorry, I'm not very familiar with this setup so I don't think I can help futher. Might be a bug? Certainly worth investigating with higher authorities

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem installing a different module (`Win32::Mutex`). This isn't a great fix, but it got the job done. From the build directory (e.g., `~/.cpan/build/The-Module-mYyzLx`)

First, set the `CC` environment variable yourself

```
SET CC=C:\strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe         [Windows]
export CC=/usr/bin/g++.exe                 [Cygwin]
```

and try to build (`perl Build.PL`, `perl Build`, ...). If it is still complaining about missing programs (`g++`, `dlltool`, etc.):

Second, copy pieces of your tool chain into the build directory

```
COPY C:\strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe .         [Windows]
COPY C:\strawberry\c\bin\dlltool.exe .

cp /usr/bin/g++ .                          [Cygwin]
cp /usr/bin/dlltool .
```

If the build still complains about missing programs, copy those to your build directory too.

The fix and the symptoms are consistent with `ExtUtils::CBuilder` not being able to use the current `PATH` setting, though I have no idea what that would be so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing these first:

apt-get install libc6-dev

and

apt-get install libtest-exception-perl

By the way you describe the problem it looks like you have these two perl modules missing. On the other hand it takes just a couple of seconds to double-check if those are installed, but these 'seconds' could help you save on a lot of head ache.